# Numerically sampling a random variable from its characteristic function

Tags: probability, reference-request, numerical-methods, random-variables

for a numerical application I would like to be able to sample a random variable directly from its characteristic function.

I found the paper below which gives an algorithm, but given that it is 40 years old I was wondering if there are alternative possibly more efficient methods known to achieve this?

http://luc.devroye.org/devroye_1981_computer_generation_random_variables_characteristic_function.pdf

Comment: I recommend that you run the title of the paper through Google Scholar. You will be able to find citations of this paper there. It is likely that one these papers develop a better algorithm.

Comment: @CarlChristian Thank you for the suggestion. I found the following more recent article: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00949655.2014.892108

Comment: @plain_coffee I would be very interested in the solution, but the paper is behind bars.. The abstract boasts that the solution could be implemented in a few lines of code. Would you mind giving a short example as an answer to your own question?